# Is there anything like ZipArchive but for sending the zip for download without generating the file on disk?

Tags: php, file, compression, zip

I want to create a zip file in PHP and use the header() function to make it downloadable without having to save the file on the server. But I think the built in ZipArchive can't do this. I found a few that can, but they all add files from existing files, and I need to add it like ZipArchive::addFromString() does.

Does someone knows a class or something with this capabilities?

Comment: As far as I know zip-archives are file-based and therefore not usable for streaming at all. You may for example use gzip, if you need a stream-based compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PHP compression streams documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) ZipArchive registers the `zip://` stream wrapper. While I never worked with `zip://` streams you could check out if `zip.compress` works. You can build a test from another example found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/filters.compression.php).

Answer (score 0):

gzip does it for a file. and for an archive you can use gzip and tar as follows.

```
tar -cz  thedir
```

this is how to do it with zip.

```
zip - file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: But gzip are not windows zip files, I need it to be a .zip

Comment: then you zip. it can go to stdout. use the -